# How to display data from json output to JSP grid table?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, grid

I am trying to display output using Struts 2 and jQuery grid. I am getting the proper JSON output. But I could not show the result page into the JSP page using Struts 2 jQuery grid. My JSON output like the following:

```
{"gridModel":[[81,1],[82,1],[83,1],[84,1],[85,1],[86,1],[87,1],[88,1],[89,1],[90,1]],"page":0,"records":10,"rows":0,"searchField":null,"searchOper":null,"searchString":null,"sidx":null,"sord":null,"total":2147483647}
```

Can you please tell me why i am unable to display the grid table. My full codes are  the following:

**Struts2 code:**

```
<action name="product" class="com.example.ProductAction">
    <result>/pages/ .jsp </result>
</action>
    
<action name="productJson" class="com.example.JSONProduct"  method="execute">
    <result type="json" />
</action>
```

**`JSONProduct.java`:**

```
public class JSONProduct  extends ActionSupport {
    List<Product> gridModel;
    private Integer rows = 0;
    private Integer page = 0;
    private String sord;
    private String sidx;
    private String searchField;
    private String searchString;
    private String searchOper;
    private Integer total = 0;
    private Integer records = 0;
    
    // getter and setter
    
    public String execute(){            
    
        int to = (rows * page);
        int from = to - rows;

        ProductDAO dao = new ProductDAO();
        records = dao.getAllProduct().size();
        
        gridModel = dao.getAllProduct();            
        total =(int) Math.ceil((double)records / (double)rows);
        System.out.println(gridModel);          
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    
    public String getJSON(){
        return execute();
    }
}
```

**`ProductAction.java`:**

```
public class ProductAction extends ActionSupport {
    public String execute(){            
        return SUCCESS;
    }   
}
```

**`Product.jsp`:**

```
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="productJson" />
<sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="redmond" />
<sjg:grid id="gridtable" caption="Data" dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}" pager="true" gridModel="gridModel"
    rowList="10,15,20" rowNum="15" rownumbers="true">
    
    <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="id" title="Product ID" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="quantity" index="quantity" title="Product quantity" />

</sjg:grid>
```

Comment: Please note that it is inconsiderate to delete a question after you have received a legitimate answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

The `sj:head` tag is used in the HTML `head` tag body. Try to move the tag to the head tag.

```
<head>
  <sj:head jqueryui="true" jquerytheme="redmond" />
  <title></title>
</head>
```

Comment: I moved that tag. But the grid table is coming without any data. Number of rows are correct to the grid table. But all the rows are blank / empty.

Comment: The total number of pages has invalid value. Make sure you have the getters and setters for fields to correctly set rows.

Comment: i checked all the getters and setters. Do i need to add some other codes into ProductAction.java file. I just write one method there like the following:

public class ProductAction extends ActionSupport {
    public String execute(){            
        return SUCCESS;
    }   
} And I do not add any other thing into that code.

Comment: Does the `remoteurl` work?  It should be like `href="%{#remoteurl}"`. Why `"rows":0`?

Comment: No, it's not necessary.

Comment: I changed the remote url. Still the same problem. And i am still getting the json output like {"gridModel":[[81,1],[82,1],[83,1],[84,1],[85,1],[86,1],[87,1],[88,1],[89,1],[90,1]],"page":0,"records":10,"rows":0,"searchField":null,"searchOper":null,"searchString":null,"sidx":null,"sord":null,"total":2147483647} into to browser when i tried to access localhost/pages/productJson

Comment: Does the package extend `json-default`? Post complete `struts.xml`.

Comment: yes like: <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="json-default,struts-default">

Comment: You have parameter `rows` isn't set. The `params` interceptor should be configured properly.

Comment: How do i do this? I add that as getter and setter.

Comment: Check your `jar files` of `struts2-jquery-grid` and `struts2-jquery-plugin` are same version. `struts2-jquery-plugin` can have higher version. .. I too had same problem long back.